# Rails: specify query scope via variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

Is there a way to add scope to an ActiveRecord query through variable?

```
if @date.present?
  result << Foo.in_region(params[:region_id]).created_since(@date)
  result << Bar.in_region(params[:region_id]).created_since(@date)
  result << Baz.in_region(params[:region_id]).created_since(@date)
else
  result << Foo.in_region(params[:region_id])
  result << Bar.in_region(params[:region_id])
  result << Baz.in_region(params[:region_id])
end
```

I would like to do somthing like:

```
scope = in_region(params[:region_id])
scope << created_since(@date) if @date.present?
%w(Foo Bar Baz).each do |model|
  result << model.scope
end
```

Of course it isn't working this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two scopes, and then simply chain them.
But for such simple query I don't see a reason for scope, it would be just

```
Foo.where(region_id: params[:region_id]).where('created_at >= ?', @date)
```

so you don't need to add scopes. If you anyway insist on scopes you can take a look at [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)